# Call other method in IlGenerator

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I'm building my own type via `TypeBuilder` and I'm trying to add to this methods that will call `methodInfo` gathered from different object.

The problem is I don't know how to use `ILGenerator.Emit` or `ILGenerator.EmitCall`.

I've tried to use `il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo, arguments)` and `il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo)` but neither of them worked. Always I got this error:

```
[InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.]
   MyImplementationController.Hello1() +0

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +192
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +155
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +19
```

And this is my code:

```
        foreach (var methodInfo in methodInfosFromSomewhere)
        {
            var arguments = methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(a => a.ParameterType).ToArray();
            MethodBuilder mb = tb.DefineMethod(
                methodInfo.Name,
                MethodAttributes.Final | MethodAttributes.Public,
                CallingConventions.HasThis,
                methodInfo.ReturnType,
                arguments);

            // method 
            ILGenerator il = mb.GetILGenerator();
            int numParams = arguments.Length;
            for (byte x = 0; x < numParams; x++)
            {
                //il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, x);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, x);
            }
            //il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo, arguments);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo);

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }
```

@Edit

Finally I know (probably) where is problem! When I'm calling `Emit.Call` I don't want to call method in this object. I want to call method from another object.

Please look at this example:

```
// this is interface that we want to 'decorate'
public interface IMyInterface
{
    MyResponse Hello1();
    MyResponse Hello2(MyRequest request);
    MyResponse Hello3(MyRequest request);
}
public class MyImplementation : IMyInterface
{
    public MyResponse Hello1()
    {
        return new MyResponse { Name = "empty" };
    }
    // ... rest of implementation, it doesn't matter
}
```

The class that I want to generate is smthing like that:

```
public class GeneratedClass : ApiController
{
    public MyInterface myImplementation { get; set; }
    public MyResponse Hello1()
    {
        return myImplementation.Hello1();
    }
    // ... rest of implementation, it doesn't matter
}
```

As you can see I want to call method from other object. I know how to create property for object but I don't know how to call method from other object

Comment: Instruction with OpCode OpCodes.Ldstr expects a string as the argument, not a byte.

Comment: Do you know the argument types of the method in advance or not? Generating a call in a fully dynamic fashion isn't for the faint of heart; you have to emit the correct (type-safe) code to load each parameter.

Comment: I got ```MethodInfo``` where there are stored. I don't know anything more

Comment: Write your generated assembly to a file by calling `DynamicAssembly.Save(...)` and then use peverify.exe to analyse why your method is invalid.

Comment: If you can not solve it this way you could create a compileable example that reproduces the circumstances of your problem and one can analyse it fully.

Comment: please look at update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source: (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/ilgenerator.cs,3e110f4a19d1c05e)

```
public virtual void Emit(OpCode opcode, MethodInfo meth)
{
    //...
    if (opcode.Equals(OpCodes.Call) || opcode.Equals(OpCodes.Callvirt) || opcode.Equals(OpCodes.Newobj))
    {
        EmitCall(opcode, meth, null);
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, `Emit()` calls `EmitCall()` if the `OpCode` is `Call`, `Callvirt`, or `Newobj`, so `Emit()` vs `EmitCall()` should not make a difference.

Emitting with `OpCodes.Ldstr` expects an operand of type `string`. What you want to do is load the arguments to the stack one by one before emitting the `OpCodes.Call` instruction.

Instead of:

```
for (byte x = 0; x < numParams; x++)
{
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, x);
}
```

Try this:

```
switch (numParams)
{
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        break;
    case 2:
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        break;
    case 3:
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
        break;
    default:
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_3);
        for (int i = 4; i < numParams; i++)
        {
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, mb.GetParameters()[i]);
        }
        break;
}
```

Edit after question update:
You must define a property `myImplementation` in your new type.

Try this:

```
// Create field to back your "myImplementation" property
FieldBuilder newBackingField = tb.DefineField("backingField_myImplementation", typeof(MyInterface), System.Reflection.FieldAttributes.Private);
// Create your "myImplementation" property
PropertyBuilder newProp = tb.DefineProperty("myImplementation", System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.None, typeof(MyInterface), Type.EmptyTypes);
// Create get-method for your property
MethodBuilder getter = tb.DefineMethod("get_myImplementation", System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Private);
ILGenerator getterILGen = getter.GetILGenerator();
// Basic implementation (return backing field value)
getterILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
getterILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, newBackingField);
getterILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Create set-method for your property
MethodBuilder setter = tb.DefineMethod("set_myImplementation", System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Private);
setter.DefineParameter(1, System.Reflection.ParameterAttributes.None, "value");
ILGenerator setterILGen = setter.GetILGenerator();
// Basic implementation (set backing field)
setterILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
setterILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
setterILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, newBackingField);
setterILGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Hello1 Method
MethodBuilder hello1 = tb.DefineMethod("Hello1", System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Public);
ILGenerator il = hello1.GetILGenerator();

// Here, add code to load arguments, if any (as shown previously in answer)

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getter);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(MyInterface).GetMethod("Hello1"));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Comment: Still got the same. BTW right now I'm testing with method that do not take any parameters (just return).

Comment: If there are no parameters, the new method will have only two instructions: 
Call (other method)
Ret

Comment: Normally it can have parameters, right now I'm just testing without. Second thing, should I use ```Emit``` or ```EmitCall```?

Comment: See revised answer - should not make a difference.